# Does ubuntu work with a HP Deskjet F2480

Tags: hp

I am thinking of updating my old XP Desktop to ubuntu. i was just wondering does ubuntu work with a HP Deskjet F2480 All in one Printer/Scanner?

I would like it to be able, to Print & Scan.

Cheers!

Carl

Answer (score 0):

Carl! This is good question. The answer to your question is YES! After installation upadte your Ubuntu and restart your computer. After restarting, just plug in your HP DeskJet F2480 into USB port/interface. You will be able to print any document! I just checked with HP and they have Linux driver for F2480! Tthe thing is you won't be able to scan as you used to scan on Windows (with HP software). You will have to find another program for scanning (for example: GIMP...). Acutally you can "import from scanner" in almost every application you are going to use (example: open office...). Don't be afarid to install and use Ubuntu. You have all the support here!

Best reagrds,
Tehnikalac